# Working with open cv on android using java not c++

Tags: android, opencv

I am working with OpenCv on android using c++ ,I want to develop using java 
Can I do that 
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, Check out this [page](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html). A cut and paste from there states:

OpenCV now has bindings for desktop Java, updating the set of supported languages to C / C++, Python, Android, Java and any JVM language which interops with Java, such as Scala and Clojure. The existing Java API for Android has recently been extended to support desktop Java as well. Unlike the popular JavaCV project, these bindings are automatically generated by parsing the OpenCV C++ headers.

There is also javacv, which can be accessed [here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv).